# Does uniform distribution on every square $[0,a]^2$ along diagonal imply uniform CDF on the entire $ [0,1]^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, correlation, copula

Let $F: [0,1]^2\to R $ be a continuous cdf with uniform marginals, i.e., $F(x,1)=x$ and $F(1,y)=y$. Suppose $F$ is symmetric, i.e., $F(x,y)=F(y,x)$.

Suppose we also know that $F(a,a)=a^2$ for all $a\in [0,1]$.

Can we conclude that $F$ is uniform distribution on $[0,1]^2$?

Thanks.

Comment: No it is not necessarily but it is hard to give an explicit counterexample. If you imagine $F$ to be the uniform cdf on $[0,1]^2$ plotted in 3D, then around $F(0.75,0.25)$ and $F(0.25,0.75)$ you could perform slight changes that keep the symmetry and the integral value is still 1 so that your stated properties are still fulfilled but you don't have the uniform distribution anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions on $F$ are really loose.

Here’s a counterexample: $F(x,y)=xy+.01xy(1-x)(1-y)(x-y)^2$.

Comment: I suspect you can increase that $.01$ to $1$ and still have densities on $[0,1]^2$ between $0$ and $1.25$ while meeting the conditions.  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx%28+d%2Fdy%28+xy+%2B+xy%281-x%29%281-y%29%28y-x%29%5E2+%29%29%2C+from+x%3D0+to+1%2C+from+y%3D0+to+1) can illustrate the densities

Comment: Probably but wasn’t confident that the densities would remain positive - you might gain a few small negative factors from the exponents.

Comment: The most straightforward bounding is that there’s 8 negative monomials of total degree at most 6 giving a density of at least $-8 \cdot (6/2)^2=-72$. Thus the total expression’s density is at least $1-.72>0$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer！ It is very helpful.

Comment: Note that you can both add/subtract the second term to get positive/negative correlation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example (which @Eric points out is not symmetric, but I deal with that later), where the joint density is $2$ in the red shaded areas and $0$ elsewhere
[image]

So for example $$\mathbb P(X \le 0.2, Y \le 0.1) = 0.03 \not= 0.02 = \mathbb P(X \le 0.2)\mathbb P(Y \le 0.1)$$ giving the desired counter example.

You can check the marginal density visually: any vertical or horizontal line has red-shaded length $\frac12$ so the marginal density is $1$, and the red-shaded area of a square with opposite vertices at $(0,0)$ and $(a,a)$ is $\frac12a^2$ so, remembering the red joint density is $2$, this meets the desired conditions.

---

*Added*

To handle the lack of symmetry, take two of these away from the diagonal following @Trailblazer's idea, so consider the next symmetric picture where the joint density is $2$ in the red shaded areas, $1$ in the blue shaded areas and $0$ elsewhere.

[image]

and now a possible calculation is  $$\mathbb P(X \le 0.7, Y \le 0.1) = 1 \times 0.5 \times 0.1+2\times \tfrac12 \times 0.1^2=0.06 \\ \not= 0.07 = \mathbb P(X \le 0.7)\,\mathbb P(Y \le 0.1)$$

Comment: This isn’t symmetric

Comment: @Eric That is a fair point.  I will leave it up because I think it is pretty

Comment: @Eric.  I have added an adapted version which is symmetric

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer！ This is very hepful. It seems that the example exhibits negative dependence？Can we further conclude that F is not positive dependent？

Comment: @sam: I do not see "negative dependence" (I assume you mean correlation) for this example

Comment: yes I think it is correlation